# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_article.reporter_id

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm following Django's official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) for Many-to-one relationships.

Create a new article, and add it to the article set:

```
>>> new_article2 = Article.objects.create(headline="Paul's story", pub_date=date(2006, 1, 17))
```

models.py include:

from django.db import models

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)
```

but when I tried to execute I got error message: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_article.reporter_id

traceback:

```
    >>> new_article2 = Article.objects.create(headline="Paul's story", pub_date=datetime.date(2006, 1, 17))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_article.reporter_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1285, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/student/PycharmProjects/DjangoGetStarted/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_article.reporter_id
```

Comment: `NOT NULL constraint `, reporter field shouldn't be null. Create one reporter record and use it while creating article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models indicate that there is a one to many relation from the `Reporter` to the `Article`, i.e. one `Reporter` can be associated with many `Articles`. Also, since the `reporter` field of the `Article` model is *not* nullable, every `Article` *must* have exactly one `Reporter` associated. That is, you must first create a `Reporter` (similar to the example in the docs you linked to):

```
>>> r = Reporter(first_name='John', last_name='Smith', email='john@example.com')
>>> r.save()
```

then associate your `Article` with that:

```
>>> a = Article(id=None, headline="This is a test", pub_date=date(2005, 7, 27), reporter=r)
>>> a.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that every Article must have exactly one Reporter associated, but what documentation says is complete opposite fact to the concept. so is it possible that documentation has done mistake over there?

Comment: It looks like you are right. I don't think `Article.objects.create` would work in that example because it will automatically try to save the `Article` object before you can assign a `Reporter` to it. The doc should have said `Article(headline=...` because that would be an in-memory instance.

Comment: Yeah! Just wanted to confirm :P.  So should we report this error?

Comment: Yes, I would submit a bug report and/or a pull request so that it can be incorporated into the next release.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `Article` instance **without `reporter`** reference, which is FK.So you hae to provide FK object or FK's pk while creating `Article` instance as below,

In [2]:

```
reporter = Reporter.objects.create(first_name='Jerin', last_name='Peter George', email='myemail@email.com')
```

In [3]:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

In [4]:

```
Article.objects.create(headline= "Jerin's story", pub_date = datetime.utcnow()<b>,reporter=reporter</b>)
```

Out[4]:

```
<Article: Paul's story>
```

If you  wish to set the reporter object as a `NULL` reference in `Article` model, you have to mention it on your Models by adding `null=True` as

```
class Article(models.Model):
headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
pub_date = models.DateField()
reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter,
                             <b>null=True,</b> on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.headline</code></pre>
```

Thus You can create article object without `reporter` reference as

```
new_article2 = Article.objects.create(headline="Paul's story", pub_date=datetime.date(2006, 1, 17))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Reporter is not defined as nullable in docs.

Comment: Then you can go with the first option,  provide reporter's pk while creating Article instance